# Show Google map in Android without using fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have seen tutorial to embed Google map in Android with the use of Fragments. But how to display map without using fragment in Layout as well as Java?

Comment: I don't get why this has been closed for being unclear. This question is very clear : How to use Google map on Android without using a MapFragment, which is the Google promoted way to do it

Answer (score 2):

[Use `MapView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html). Quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview):

> MapView, a subclass of the Android View class, allows you to place a map in an Android View. A View represents a rectangular region of the screen, and is a fundamental building block for Android applications and widgets. Much like a MapFragment, the MapView acts as a container for the map, exposing core map functionality through the GoogleMap object.
>
> Users of this class must forward all the activity life cycle methods - such as onCreate(), onDestroy(), onResume(), and onPause() - to the corresponding methods in the MapView class.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `MapView` to view hierarchy. Make sure to read the docs through and through as you have to delegate lots of stuff.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html